# How to disable yum repositories not managed by puppet

Tags: redhat, puppet, yum

Trying to bring a very ad-hoc environment into a more standardized and managed state.

In my use-case, I'd like to disable all non-Red Hat repositories (provided by the subscription-manager plugin). However, would be nice to have a flexible solution that disables all repositories not managed by Puppet.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `file { '/path/to/repos.d': ensure => directory, recurse => true, purge => true }` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on how you provide the  repo config through puppet. Do you place a file under /etc/yum/repos.d or  a custom provider?

You could take measures to make sure that the /etc/yum.repos.d/ dir is purged (ie kept free from files not provided by puppet), check the file resource in the puppet type reference for details.
Problem with this approach is that some 3rd party applications provide their own repos and package them into rpm:s which gets installed during puppet runtime. This can be hard to take into account when writing the puppetclasses.

Depending on how you plan to implement your yum repo config, I suggest you change the "reposdir" in /etc/yum.conf to something like "/etc/yum.repos.managed.d/", and place your puppet configured repos in that directory. That way, yum will not read anything from the standard repo config directory, and only from the ones provided by your puppet implementation.

Comment: Excellent outside the box solution. This may be what I go with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make Puppet do that?

Tell Puppet to enable only those repositories which need to be enabled and disable everything else.

Another idea, add some prefix to your Puppet managed repo names, so you can easily identify them. Then disable everything except for RedHat and prefixed repos.

Comment: Yea, that is what I want to do but can't figure out an elegant approach. Will think about it some more.

Comment: not using puppet but cfengine, we just overwrite the /etc/yum.repos.d/ folder with the repos we want to use.